# For loop delay before next iteration

Tags: javascript

I have to add the delay in the loop so that next audio will play after the completion of the previous audio 
For that i need delay before moving to the next iteration .

Code Snippet

```
 for (var i=0; i<=total_units; i++) { 
    var audio;
    switch (dispatch_units[i]) {
        case 'ST39':
        audio = new Audio('sounds/alert1.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ALS':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/monty_engine.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ST38':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/twotone.mp3');
            break;
    }
    audio.play();                               
 }
```

Any Help will be appreciated for adding the delay of 5 sec

Comment: Listen for `onended` event => `object.addEventListener("ended", myScript);`

Comment: **[`audio ended event`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)**

Comment: use `setTimeout(funcTobeExecuted,1000);` to call audio after some 1 sec delay(which has to be replaced with songs duration). ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delay the execution of the `for` loop in a way that won't have serious UI issues.

Instead, use a sequence of callbacks to play the next item five seconds after the previous one ends:

```
var i = 0;
runOne();
function runOne() {
    var audio;
    switch (dispatch_units[i]) {
        case 'ST39':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/alert1.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ALS':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/monty_engine.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ST38':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/twotone.mp3');
            break;
    }
    // If it's impossible for `audio` not to be set here, you can simplify this
    if (audio) {
        audio.addEventListener("ended", runNext);
        audio.play();
    } else {
        setTimeout(runNext, 0);
    }

    function runNext() {
        audio.removeEventListener("ended", runNext);
        ++i;
        if (i <= total_units) {
            setTimeout(runOne, 5000);    // <=== 5000ms = 5 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

That's using the `ended` event that Rayon Dabre pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938018/for-loop-delay-before-next-iteration/35938187#comment59532422_35938018), but you can substitute any other event as necessary.

If you don't want to wait until it ends, it's even simpler: Just remove the `ended` callback and directly call `setTimeout(runNext, 5000)` after starting each of them:

```
var i = 0;
runOne();
function runOne() {
    var audio;
    switch (dispatch_units[i]) {
        case 'ST39':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/alert1.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ALS':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/monty_engine.mp3');
            break;
        case 'ST38':
            audio = new Audio('sounds/twotone.mp3');
            break;
    }
    // If it's impossible for `audio` not to be set here, you can simplify this
    if (audio) {
        audio.play();
    }
    ++i;
    if (i <= total_units) {
        setTimeout(runOne, audio ? 5000 : 0);    // <=== 5000ms = 5 seconds
    }
}
```

---

Side note: It's unusual to start with `0` and go through `<= total_units`. Normally if you start with `0` you go through `< total_units`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to do that.

To stop the interval, use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Code example

```
var i = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function() {
  var audio;
  switch (dispatch_units[i]) {
    case 'ST39':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/alert1.mp3');
      break;
    case 'ALS':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/monty_engine.mp3');
      break;
    case 'ST38':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/twotone.mp3');
      break;
  }
  audio.play();
  i++;
  if(i<=total_units) {
      clearInterval(loop);
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You can, but if the audio clips are  more or less than five seconds long, it'll get ugly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But the OP say `Any Help will be appreciated for adding the delay of 5 sec`

Comment: Yes, and perhaps they really meant it. More likely, in my view, they don't want the audio overlapping in that case, but...

Comment: these are dispatch units alarms of the rescue system